# parseInt() scientific notation

Tags: javascript

Was playing around with JS and noticed this.

Why does `parseInt(1e+21)` return `1` and `parseInt(1e+20)` return `100000000000000000000` ? `parseInt(10e+20)` also returns `1`?

Why does `parseInt(1.7976931348623157E+10308);` return `NaN` while `parseFloat(1.7976931348623157E+10308)` returns `Infinity`?

---

Even made a fibonacci sequence and any value that has `+21` exponents only returns the first digit:

[image: fibonacci sequence scientific notation]

`parseFloat()` will return the correct number till Infinity.

[Fibonacci demo (int : parseInt() : parseFloat())](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/518hckmy/4/)

( tested in Chrome )

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt` and `parseFloat` are supposed to parse **strings** and convert them to `Number`s. So, when you pass them a `Number`, it gets coerced to a string by the interpreter. So, at least in Firefox, `"" + 1e+20` outputs `"100000000000000000000"`, and `"" + 1e+21` outputs `"1e+21"`.

Let's read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) of `parseInt`:

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point

so `parseInt("1.whatever")` returns `1` and `parseInt("32.231e+something")` returns 32.

A similar thing must be happening with `parseFloat`.

It's the weak typing's fault. IMO the correct behaviour when doing what you do would be to throw an exception.

Comment: Why does parseInt(1e+20) return 100000000000000000000 and not 1 then?

Comment: I said it already. When `1e+20` gets coerced to a string, it outputs `"100000000000000000000"`, which gets parsed` to the correct number. `1e+21` outputs `"1e+21"` instead.

Try the "" + <number> sums I wrote in the answer.

Comment: I did. parseInt(""+1e+21) outputs 1

Comment: No, I mean run "" + 1e+21, without the parseInt. Same with 1e+20